# Python 3.2.2 ctypes.Structure initialize c_void_p to None

Tags: ctypes, python-3.2

a simple class yields this weird behaviour on 32-bit Windows 7. I'm trying to passes an array of this structure to my dll and then trying to get content of packets filled by the dll. I discovered that the c_void_p is a NoneType object right when I created an object of this class. is this the normal behaviour?

```
import ctypes
class io_packet( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [( 'size', ctypes.c_uint32 ),
                ( 'header', ctypes.c_uint32 ),
                ( 'string1_size', ctypes.c_uint32 ),
                ( 'string2_size', ctypes.c_uint32 ),
                ( 'string1', ctypes.c_char * 128 ),
                ( 'string2', ctypes.c_char * 64 ),
                ( 'virt_handle', ctypes.c_void_p ), ]

a = io_packet()
a.size
a.header
a.string1_size
a.string2_size
a.string1
a.string2
a.virt_handle
```

Comment: I expected value of virt_handle to always be same type. it's very confusing to see same member in structure to be as either NoneType or int type, but None type is not the same as 0x0 in python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal.  `size` and `header` are initialized to zero, so it unsurprising that `virt_handle` is initialized to None, which is the equivalent of NULL for pointers in Python.  `ctypes` is returning the Python *value* when the structure elements are read from Python.

Another example:

```
>>> a=c_void_p()
>>> a
c_void_p(None)
>>> a.value
>>> type(a.value)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> a=c_void_p(1)
>>> a
c_void_p(1)
>>> a.value
1
>>> type(a.value)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: checking for a proper value with this code if a.virt_handle > 0x1000: #do_something would throw exception instead of skipping the statement in the if statement, so it forces me to write additional statement for if a.virt_handle is None: #do_nothing and change the original if to elif

Comment: "if a.virt_handle > 0x1000: #do_something" would throw exception without "if a.virt_handle is None: #do_nothing". this is because None is unorderable type.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't design ctypes, but handles should be opaque anyway.  If your app is testing the value of the handle other than "not None" that's a design issue.  If you have the freedom to change the app, you could use a fixed-sized integer handle and use `c_int` instead of `c_void_p`.  Otherwise, you're stuck with `if a.virt_handle and a.virt_handle > 0x1000: #do_something`.0x1000.